# Delete non-intersecting parts of two solids

Tags: intersection

Is it possible to extrude an imported curve, duplicate it, rotate the duplicate 90 degrees on center, and then retain only the intersection of the two extrusions?

Comment: Just for completeness .. which axis of rotation? In the plane of the curve, or perpendicular to it?

Comment: I'm a hobbies trying to move from 123D Design (no longer supported). I'm wanting to take the intersection of symmetrical letter forms extruded, duplicated, and rotated on their axis of symmetry.